# Math.random().toString.slice is not a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-directives

I'm trying to set up a custom directive on Vue JS 2. But I got this error message:

```
TypeError: Math.random(...).toString.slice is not a function
```

Here is my directive written globally on main.js:

```
Vue.directive('rainbow', {
  bind (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.style.color = '#' + Math.random().toString.slice(2, 8)
  }
})
```

Here is where I'm calling my directive

```
<h2 v-rainbow>Hello</h2>
```

I searched everywhere on the web but info.
Any help or suggestions is more than welcome. Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toString` is a function, so you have to use it in the following way:

```
Math.random().toString().slice(2, 8)
----------------------^^^---------
```

Comment: God! How I didn't see this! I' quite ashamed but very thankful. 5*

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to generate random color, then this is the correct way:

```
var colorNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff); 
// converting to hexadecimal 
var colorNumberStr = colorNumber.toString(16);  
// added 0-s to have fixed 6-length string
var colorNumberStrPadded = ('00000' + colorNumberStr).slice(-6) 
el.style.color = '#' + colorNumberStrPadded;
```